# Android Firebase, server side filtering for Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Following is my firebase data structure

```
{
  "ticketing" : {
    "1476639649079-mahto" : {
      "agentId" : 0,
      "agent_status" : "1_Dispatched",
      "approverId" : 0,
      "contractorId" : 0,
      "dateTime" : "16-10-2016 13:40 PM",
      "priority" : "MEDIUM",
      "requester" : {
        "issue" : "issue 3",
        "location" : "location 3",
        "priority" : "Medium",
        "shop" : "shop 3",
        "site" : "site 3",
        "userInfo" : {
          "email" : "m@gmail.com",
          "firstname" : "mahto",
          "isLoggedin" : true,
          "lastname" : "pancha",
          "loggedin" : true,
          "number" : "123123123",
          "password" : "q",
          "role" : "fieldagent",
          "userid" : "2",
          "username" : "q"
        }
      },
      "requesterId" : 2,
      "status" : "Incoming",
      "ticketNumber" : "1476639649079-mahto"
    },
    "1476741838857-mahto" : {
      "agentId" : 1,
      "agent_status" : "1_Incoming",
      "approverId" : 0,
      "contractorId" : 0,
      "dateTime" : "17-10-2016 18:03 PM",
      "priority" : "HIGH",
      "requester" : {
        "issue" : "Description 3",
        "location" : "Location 3",
        "priority" : "HIGH",
        "shop" : "shop 3",
        "site" : "site 3",
        "userInfo" : {
          "email" : "m@gmail.com",
          "firstname" : "mahto",
          "isLoggedin" : true,
          "lastname" : "pancha",
          "loggedin" : true,
          "number" : "123123123",
          "password" : "q",
          "role" : "fieldagent",
          "userid" : "2",
          "username" : "q"
        }
      },
      "requesterId" : 2,
      "status" : "Incoming",
      "ticketNumber" : "1476741838857-mahto"
    }
  }
}
```

Database refrence

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ticketing");
        mDatabase.orderByChild("agent_status").equalTo("1_Incoming");
```

and attached to recyclerview adapter

```
 mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ticket, AgentTicketHolder>(Ticket.class, R.layout.agent_ticket_cardview, AgentTicketHolder.class, mDatabase) { .. }
```

My expected result is that i will get only one node i.e **1476741838857-mahto** which has agent_status value equal to **1_Incoming**.

But i'am getting both the nodes in my recylerview.

[image]

Comment: Post you EventListener in your question,check your EventListener whether it is added to database reference or query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call filtering methods, the Firebase SDK returns *a new object* for the resulting query. So you need to capture the reference to that object and pass *that* into the adapter:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ticketing");

Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("agent_status").equalTo("1_Incoming");

mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ticket, AgentTicketHolder>
    (Ticket.class, R.layout.agent_ticket_cardview, AgentTicketHolder.class, query) { .. }
```